Is it a problem that a sill plate is not flush with foundation outer wall?
I'm planning to install a 1.5" rigid insulation over the sheathing on my new home. I will also add 1" furring strips to support the siding. That adds up to 2.5" total.
My goal is to make furring strips flush with the foundation wall. To do that, I would like to use 6" (5.5") sill plates and make them flush on the inside, which leaves me with exactly 2.5" of space for my insulation and furring.
My concern is that every house I've seen has sill plates flush with the outside walls, not the inside. Is there a rule that says no to recessed sill plates, or a rule that says that the sill plates must be installed flush? Is this a sane idea, given that I will have a drip edge going behind the rigid insulation?


The only concerns are proper bearing for the load path and flashing for drainage. You seem to have both covered. I've seen homes with just 2½" of sill bearing due to floor truss sizing problems, and I've seen them with the walls hanging off the foundation due to poor foundation layout. It's not a concern, within reason.
It's also somewhat common to intentionally oversize the foundation (or undersize the framing) specifically to allow for this type of insulation. In general, it's discretionary how one aligns the framing and the foundation.
Carry on.
